# Can I transform my DVD drive in Acer TravelMate into an HDD case?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, sockets, acer-travelmate

I would like to transform my DVD drive into HDD/SSD socket in my Acer TravelMate 5742G (so that I can use 2 hard drives). I have been looking for something similar on the webm, but unfortunately I have not found anything.

Is this possible? Has anyone done something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [NewmodeUS](http://www.newmodeus.com/shop/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=2_45&zenid=144fef1d53be012aa5d5a5f87babef2c)  I have used their adapters for Dell and Lenovo.  They have some Acer adapters

Comment: I took a look on that but they are about 42$ each. I can find something similar on eBay for 10 - 15$ but I have not found an adapter for Acer Travel 5742g.

Comment: I have used many from NewmodeUS and all ahve been good.  Fast shipment and great service.  Worth the money.  Tried others and when I had an issue, no response.